# Difference between background-size:cover and background-size:contain

Tags: html, css, background

Visually I can appreciate the difference, but in which situations should I prefer one over the other?
Is there any point using them at all or can they be replaced by percentages?

Currently I don't seem to be able to go beyond a trial-error approach when using these properties, which does my head in.

Also I can only find pretty vague explanations and especially I find the [W3C doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) quite baffling.

> Values have the following meanings:
>
> ‘contain’
>
> Scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio
>   (if any), to the largest size such that both its width and its height
>   can fit inside the background positioning area.
>
> ‘cover’
>
> Scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any), to the
>   smallest size such that both its width and its height can completely
>   cover the background positioning area.

I'm probably being a bit thick, but can anyone give me a plain English explanation with relative examples?

Please use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxyz2evq/1/). Thanks.

**CSS**

```
body{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Bachalpseeflowers.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

***Note***

The accepted answer is the one I currently find the most concise and complete.
Thanks everybody for their help.

Comment: Have you seen the [examples with explanations on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images)?

Comment: This is an interesting question - the spec does not describe any practical use cases for either of these values and, quite frankly, even I haven't had any opportunity to use them myself. That being said, keep in mind that the reason these two keywords exist is because they cannot be expressed using any combination of length/percentage/auto values.

Comment: I do think this page visualises it quite nicely: http://tutorialzine.com/2012/06/quick-tip-fullscreen-backgrounds/

Comment: @Vucko: Those examples look very contrived. Why would anyone use a logo as a background, let alone size it in either manner? Sure, they demonstrate how contain and cover work, but as the OP said, they're able to visually appreciate the difference, and that is not quite what they're asking.

Comment: @Vucko thanks, I did see those, but as already said, I thought the examples were a bit useless.

Comment: @BoltClock Where does it say that they should use a logo as a background? MDN is from mozilla so it's logical that they will use an image that represents them, isn't it?

Comment: @Vucko: It doesn't say that, but then the author deliberately chose to use a logo for all the examples anyway, and even lampshades it as such: "(for some reason likely involving horrifyingly bad site design)" It's pretty clear that these weren't meant to be real-world examples so much as demonstrations of how the property works, and therefore they aren't very useful to this question.

Comment: @MackieeE thanks for the link. It does show the behaviour nicely. It still unclear to me why we should use them at all.

Comment: @BoltClock well, for that you'll have to ask the author why did he used a logo. Anyway, mdn is a public wiki so you're always welcome to contribute to it. I believe everyone would appreciate it, expecaly if someone with your knowledge contributes :)

Comment: A usecase I have hit for `background-size:cover` is to avoid "empty spaces" on top/bottom or left/right when you don't know wether the background image will be landscape or portrait orientated. This can't be achieved with percent values.

Comment: Example here with landscape and portrait orientated images : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/argb4g0a/

Comment: [Have you read this?](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AYgjDuQwYNMC&pg=PA178&lpg=PA178&dq=difference+between+background+cover+and+contain&source=bl&ots=8JqxLJvSCg&sig=XYi_3d10NBPpv_dqNSarRO6oDgg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LUS2VKiMBY35auizgagJ&ved=0CFMQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=difference%20between%20background%20cover%20and%20contain&f=false)

Comment: @web-tiki thanks, I think you got it. Happy to accept that as an answer if you care to make your comments into one.

Comment: Sorry , but the day that we start trying to define best practices regarding something as subjective as what looks best as a background images will be the day that i throw best practices out the window.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can consider looking at the pseudocodes that govern the output. The values allotted to the image's size depend directly on the aspect ratios of container wrt aspect ratio of the background image.

***Note:*** **`Aspect ratio = width / height`**

### **Contain**

```
if (aspect ratio of container > aspect ratio of image)
    image-height = container-height
    image-width = aspect-ratio-preserved width

else
    image-width = container width
    image-height = aspect-ratio-preserved height
```

---

### **Cover**

```
if (aspect ratio of container > aspect ratio of image)
    image-width = container width
    image-height = aspect-ratio-preserved height

else
    image-height = container height
    image-width = aspect-ratio-preserved width
```

You see the relation? In both `cover` and `contain`, aspect ratio is preserved. But the if - else conditions reverse in both the cases.

This is what makes `cover` to cover full page, without any white portion visible. When aspect ratio of container is greater, scaling image so that its width becomes equal to container width. Now, height will be greater, as aspect ratio is smaller. Thus it covers the whole page without any white portion.

**Q. Can they be replaced by percentages?**

No, not simply by percentages. You'll need conditioning.

**Q. In which situations should I prefer one over the other?**

When you are creating a website, you wouldn't want any white portion in the fixed background. So use `cover`.

**`contain`** on the other can be used when you are using a repeating background (e.g. when you have a pattern image with very high aspect ratio wrt veiwport/container you can use `contain` and set `background-repeat` to `repeat-y`). But a more appropriate use for `contain` would be for a fixed height/width element.

Comment: I resized the windows and tried to find a relation. This may be how the browsers are rendering them.

Answer (score 19):

Although the question assumes the reader already understands how the `contain` and `cover` values for `background-size` work, here's a plain-English paraphrasing of what the spec says, which can serve as a quick primer:

- `background-size: contain` ensures that the entire background image will fit the background area, keeping its original aspect ratio. If the background area is smaller than the image, the image will shrink so that it can fit the background area. If the background area is either taller or wider than the image, then any parts of the area not occupied by the main image will either be filled by repetitions of the image, or [letterboxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_%28filming%29)/whitespace if `background-repeat` is set to `no-repeat`.
- `background-size: cover` makes the background image as large as possible such that it will fill the entire background area leaving no gaps. The difference between `cover` and `100% 100%` is that the aspect ratio of the image is preserved, so no unnatural stretching of the image occurs.

Note that neither of these two keyword values can be expressed using any combination of lengths, percentages, or `auto` keywords.

So when do you use one over the other? Personally, I think `cover` has more practical uses than `contain`, so I will go with that first.<sup>1</sup>

#### background-size: cover

One common use case of `background-size: cover` is in a full-screen layout where the background image is rich in detail, such as a photo, and you want to feature this image *prominently*, albeit as a background as opposed to the main content.

You want just enough of the image to be able to completely cover the browser viewport or screen, regardless of the aspect ratio of the viewport, or whether the image or the viewport is in portrait or landscape. You're not concerned if any parts of the image are cropped out as a result of this, as long as the image fills up the entire background area and maintains its original aspect ratio.

Here's an example of [a layout where the content is housed in a semitransparent white background, which hovers over a full-screen background](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/w6dp3tp1). When you increase the height of the preview pane, notice that the image automatically scales up to ensure that it still covers the entire preview area.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Bachalpseeflowers.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

body {
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    margin: 5em auto;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

If you use `background-size: contain` instead, what happens is that the background image shrinks in order for the entire image to fit in the preview pane. This leaves [ugly white letterboxes around the image depending on the aspect ratio of the preview pane](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/w6dp3tp1/1), which ruins the effect.

#### background-size: contain

So why would one use `background-size: contain` if it leaves ugly blank spaces around the image? One use case that immediately comes to mind is if the designer doesn't care about the blank spaces, so long as the entire image fits within the background area.

That may sound contrived, but consider that not every image looks *bad* with empty space around it. This is where the example of using a logo instead of a photo actually demonstrates this best, even though you probably won't find yourself using a logo as a background image.

A logo is typically an irregular shape sitting on either a blank or completely transparent background. This leaves a *canvas* that can be filled by a solid color or a different background. Using `background-size: contain` will ensure that the entire image fits the background without any parts of it being cropped out, but the image still looks right at home on the canvas.

But it doesn't necessarily have to apply to an irregularly-shaped image. It can apply to rectangular images as well. As long as you require that no cropping of the background image occurs, whitespace can either be seen as a reasonable tradeoff, or not a big deal at all. Remember fixed-width layouts? Think of `background-size: contain` as essentially that, but for background images and in both portrait and landscape orientations: if you can ensure that the content will always fit the boundaries of the background image at all times, then whitespace becomes a non-issue altogether.

Although `background-size: contain` will work whether or not the image is set to repeat, I can't think of any good use cases involving repeating backgrounds.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Note that if you're using a [gradient](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#gradients) as a background, both `contain` and `cover` have no effect because gradients do not have any intrinsic dimensions. In both cases, the gradient will stretch to cover the container, as though you had specified `100% 100%`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. A couple of things: 1) while talking about `cover` you said "regardless of the aspect ratio". I thought both `cover` and `contain` _do_ preserve the aspect ratio of the image. 2) In your code is `background-position: center center;` really necessary?

Comment: @Dura: 1) I'll edit my answer to make that clearer. It looks like I forgot to provide an example for `contain` as well. 2) Somewhat - the default position is in the top-left corner, and while it won't affect how the image scales, it will affect how it is positioned. If the image looks better anchored to the top-left corner, that is fine, but this is mostly stylistic.

Comment: Thanks for the update. About your last point: I can think of an example of repeating backgrounds when the image is a pattern.

Answer (score 6):

`background-size:cover` will cover the entire div with the image. This could be useful for showing thumbnail images of a main image where the entire image being displayed isn't that important, but you still want to conform to a size for all images. (for example, a blog post excerpt)

`background-size:contain` will show the entire image within the div. This can be useful if you specifically want to display the entirety of the images, but within a set container div size. (For example, a collection of company logos)

Both keep the image at the same aspect ratio

http://cdn.onextrapixel.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/cover-contain.jpg

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really mention in which situations I should use one over the other.

Comment: @Dura I have tried to add two scenarios to apply to these, hopefully they help!

Answer (score 2):

```
background-size:contain;
```

When using `contain` you may still see white-spacing, due to the way that it sizes and contains itself within the element.

```
background-size:cover;
```

will completely cover said element, you will not see any white-spacing

source:

http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

see example H

edit: use `background-size:contain` if:
You want it so that your image is always displayed in the viewport. Please note that: while you can see the full image, it will leave white spacing either on the top or bottom of the image whenever the aspect ratio of the browser and window are not the same.

use `background-size:cover` if:
You want a background-image, but you don't want the negative effect of the white-spacing which contain does have, please note that: when using `background-size:cover;` you may experience that it will cut off some of the image.

source: http://alistapart.com/article/supersize-that-background-please

Comment: Thanks, this seems on the right track, but it's still missing use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Contain:- Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area.
Exmaple:
Cover:-Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area.
Example:

Answer (score -1):

We had a huge conversation about cover vs contain just want to share this thoughts:

1. landscape image on landscape screen - best to use **cover**
2. portrait image on landscape screen - best to use **contain**
3. portrait image on landscape screen - best to use **contain**
4. portrait image on landscape screen - best to use **contain**

Illustration:

```
if(iDonPutSomeCode) const result = iCantPasteLinkToCodePen
```

https://codepen.io/Kinosura/pen/EGZbdy?editors=1100