# How do browsers render background-size values?

Tags: html, css, browser, rendering

The positive response to [a question I've recently asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939971/difference-between-background-sizecover-and-background-sizecontain) made me curious about how browsers render web pages.

I've found [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/) very interesting, but many things are above my head.

In particular, I am interested in what the logic behind rendering background-size values is.

My preferred answer to the linked question includes this helpful suggestion for the `contain` and `cover` values:

### **Contain**

```
if (aspect ratio of container > aspect ratio of image)
    image-height = container height
    image-width = aspect-ratio-preserved width

else
    image-width = container width
    image-height = aspect-ratio-preserved height
```

### **Cover**

```
if (aspect ratio of container > aspect ratio of image)
    image-width = container width
    image-height = aspect-ratio-preserved height

else
    image-height = container height
    image-width = aspect-ratio-preserved width
```

Also, assuming that something like that is checked in the rendering process, does it changes across browsers?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Here is how they should do that http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size, if there are general rules they will be in the specs

Comment: @Luizgrs I've already commented on the spec in the question I linked above.