# image repeat when decrease browser size

Tags: html, css

In my login page the background-image repeat it self whenever decrease the browser size. I searched it again again and apply all the available suggestions and codes but failed to remove the repetition. So please help me to remove this repetition.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-  scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Themes/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Themes/css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
        .alertify-notifier .ajs-message.ajs-error{
    color: white;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-image: url('../../../Images/BackgroundImages/Login.jpg'); background-size: 100%,100%;" onload="authenticateuser()">
    <div class="form-box" id="login-box" style="box-shadow: 0 16px 32px 0 rgba(167, 172, 170, 0.62), 0 24px 80px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
        <div class="header">
            Sign In
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- jQuery 2.0.2 -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/alertify.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show only relevant code. Have you tried `background-repeat: no-repeat`?

Comment: I think just set background-repeat: no-repeat in your body style then done.

Comment: The best way to handle using jQuery, create multiple classes and add/remove class based on screen size, this will fix your problem

Comment: yup think the same :) you also can use `background-size: cover` [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: yes i have tried also background-repeat: no-repeat it's work but when I decrease the browser width the image height decreases much smaller as compare to browser height

Comment: you could use `contain` . see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to see what's wrong without a working Fiddle or something similar, but there's a CSS property called [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat) which is probably what you're looking for. You should set it to `no-repeat` if you want to avoid the background picture being tiled over the whole area of the `div`.

Based on your comment, what else you need is `background-size: cover` to keep the size largest possible. Note that this will cut out a part of the background image if it is not the same aspect ratio as the container size.

Comment: #Lazar_Ljubenvic yes i have tried also background-repeat: no-repeat it's work but when I decrease the browser width the image height decreases much smaller as compare to browser height

Comment: Updated the answer. Not sure what you're after without a reproduction.

Comment: i have used background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:cover; but through these attributes when i resize my Browser the image height disturbed

Answer (score 0):

add style as below

```
<style>
body {
   background-image: url('../../../Images/BackgroundImages/Login.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:cover;
}
</style>
```

Comment: i have used background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:cover; but through these attributes when i resize my Browser the image height disturbed.

Comment: #Suvana_Chavan problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're trying to accomplish with 100% coverage you need to also use `background-size: cover` in your styles.  you can also use the `background-position` property to position your background image because when you use cover, it's going to get cropped differently at different sizes because it's set to fill regardless of size.  I usually use media queries in combination with `background-position` to make sure it looks good at different sizes.

```
<body style="background-image: url('../../../Images/BackgroundImages/Login.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat" onload="Verify()">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Answer (score 0):

try to use `background-size:contain`  and `background-repeat:no-repeat`

```
<body style="background-image: url('../../../Images/BackgroundImages/Login.jpg'); background-size: contain; background-repeat:no-repeat" onload="Verify()">
```

you could write it simplified :

```
<body style="background: url('../../../Images/BackgroundImages/Login.jpg') no-repeat scroll center center / contain transparent;" onload="Verify()">
```

to see the differences between `contain` and `cover` see here :
[Difference between background-size:cover and background-size:contain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939971/difference-between-background-sizecover-and-background-sizecontain)