# Image 100% height of container - min-height behaves differently on Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, safari

I want the image to fill the height of its container and then use `object-fit: cover` to take care of the aspect ratio. In Chrome this achieves the desired effect. However, in Safari the containing divs are now very tall.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjzPvN

Why is there a discrepancy between Chrome and Safari? Which one is correct and if Safari is correct, is there a better way to achieve this, preferably without using `position: absolute`?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy I'm not sure you actually understand how it works as your explanation is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari does it correctly, because of the wrong support for `min-height` by Chrome.
If you need consistency, you must use `vh`, this way:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `object-fit:` to do what you need because of its [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit)

For the best browser support, you could use instead of an image, a background-image like this:

```
.row
  .medium-8.columns
    a.link#image-1 href="" # I use and id to manage the background image but you could use a class or even inline style (not suggested)

  .medium-4.columns
    a.link#image-2 href=""
```

And your css:

```
/* I fix the container height to fit the 100% of the page  */
html, body, .row, .row > div {
    height: 100%;
}

/* If you want a fixed height you could add it here and remove the style above. */
[id^="image-"] {
    background-size: cover; /* This could be "cover" or "100% 100%"
    The difference is that the second distor the image to make it fit.*/ 
    background-position: center;
}

#image-2 { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/300x150); }
#image-1 { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x300); }
```

Here is my [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/xWaZzo/pen/yVORPx).

Please notice that If you want to get exactlye the same result as your CodePen, you should change `background-size` to `100% 100%` but if you want the image to maintain it's aspect ratio you should consider using `cover` or `contain`. Read more about the differences between [cover and contain here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939971/difference-between-background-sizecover-and-background-sizecontain#answer-27941378)

Comment: Thanks, but the question was how to solve an issue with `object-fit: cover`, not an alternative. The image is part of the content.

Comment: @DanChristian you said "…is there a better way to achieve this, preferably without using position: absolute?" You asked for an alternative. No need for a -1.

Comment: @DanChristian `object-fit` support from Safari 9.1 only (http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)

Comment: @xWaZzo I asked for an alternative if the way Safari has implemented `object-fit: cover` in this example was correct. Not just any random alternative.

Comment: @kukkuz I fully understand the support of this element. This isn't a factor in my question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Chrome calculates the row height according to the highest image. Safari does not calculate the row height according to the images.
Even if you set a fixed column height, the behavior of Safari 9.x and Chrome is not the same. The left img is showing outside its container in Safari. To make the browser behave the same, I had to set a height and make overflow-y hidden.

Example:

```
.columns {
  padding-left: .9375rem;
  padding-right: .9375rem;
  min-width: initial;
  background: blue;
  height: 405 px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Instead of overflow hidden. You can try:

```
.columns {
  padding-left: .9375rem;
  padding-right: .9375rem;
  min-width: initial;
  background: blue;
  height: 405px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Maybe you can set the height of the columns according to the highest of the two images using some jQuery. Or set the height using @media rules.

Microsoft browsers does not support `object-fit:` - Including IE11 and EDGE. For browsers not supporting `object-fit:`, you can try [object-fit-polyfill](https://github.com/constancecchen/object-fit-polyfill)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having this issue with a variable height wrapper and Safari this seemed to work for me:

```
.imgContainer {
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 100%; // for safari
}

.imgContainer > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  min-height: 100%; // for safari
}
```